# Problem, to open .deb package?

Tags: 13.04

I am using U13.04 & having problem with Libre Office.Thus,I've decided to give a try on Free Office. I've downloaded the .deb file .I'm trying to install it by clicking the package but a folder pops up, given below:

[image]

How can i install Free Office.
Any help is Appreciated !

Comment: Where do you get "Free Office" from?

Comment: http://www.freeoffice.com/

Comment: Have a look at [**How do I install a .deb file via the command line?**](http://askubuntu.com/a/40781/179042). This should guide you how to do so. Firstly, try `sudo dpkg -i your-pack_name.deb` & if any errors appear, please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gdebi` to install free office.
To do this open a **terminal** and type  the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Once gdebi is installed,right click on the .deb file and select open with gdebi as shown below.
[image]

Now you will see the `gdebi` window,click on install package.
[image]

Comment: @adityapatil, installing gdebi shouldn't be necessary. If you choose "Open with Ubuntu Software Center" that will do the job as well.

Comment: @vasa1 I know that but USC requires working internet connection,gdebi doesn't(if you have all dependencies resolved,which is the case in this question)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`. If you got error after installing, type `sudo apt-get -f install`,this will install required files.